# Laying out images in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, layout, uiscrollview

I am displaying a number of images within a UIScrollView.

I also have a button on the view, which when pressed will expand the view as shown:

```
- (IBAction) expandButtonTouched {
    NSLog(@"Expand Button Touched");
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 410); // New scrollview location
    CGRect scrollviewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 380);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveAndStrech" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    self.frame = frame;
    scrollView.frame = scrollviewFrame;

    [self layoutScrollImages];


    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

My layout images method is defined as such:

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
        }
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
}
```

The problem is, after resizing the scroll view, the content within it isnt reordered. It still only displays a single row of images, where I would like it to display as such (based on 9 images per page):

```
1 2 3 | 10 11 12 | 19 20 21
4 5 6 | 13 14 15 | 22 23 24
7 8 9 | 16 17 18 | 25 26 27 (and so on)
```

Comment: you can also lose the UIImageView* declaration as well just have          for (UIImageView* view in subviews){.......

Comment: @Matt Scrollbars in UIScrollView are in [UIScrollView subviews] too.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the curXLoc in your code but never set its y location, you cant expect to resize the scrollview and for it to start pushing content into the extra space unless you modify your layout code to take the y location into account.

i would have some code that checks the available height (y) and if there is enough space add an extra row. You will need to decide whether you fill rows or columns first because it will affect the order that items are displayed

from your code it seems you want to fill rows first, so you will need to define how many items are on a row and change your looping code so it moves the x value back to the start when a new row begins... there is not automated way to do this, even your own code shows you are just adjusting the x values...

this line of code

```
frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
```

has a literal of 0 for y, you need to add more logic to decide whether you will adjust the y value based on the height of the scroll view

Comment: Matt would it be possible for me to send you a little example code over?

Comment: Hi, sorry, ive been away for a few days, yes you can send me some example code maffyoo@gmail.com